# scaling UIImages for higher res iPhone displays using only the 3.2 SDK

Tags: uiimageview, uiimage, scaling

So the problem I'm having is I have a UIImageView that is 100 x 100 on the iPhone (200 by 200 on the iPhone 4). I'm retrieving an image from a server that is 200 by 200 pixels and setting my UIImageView to it.

This looks fine on the iPhone, but looks blurry on the iPhone 4. I think my problem has to do with UIImage scale property, but since I cannot use or build for the 4.0 SDK, I'm kind of stuck. Anyone have ideas on how to scale images properly for the iPhone 4 using the 3.2 SDK?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

iPhone 4 will only runs iOS 4 and upward. I do not think your case is possible.

Comment: iPhone 4 can run apps that are deployed and built using the 3.2 SDK no? Not everyone has updated their apps to be iOS4 compliant.

Comment: The OS running on a phone and the SDK used to develop apps are too different things.